# How to I tell salt to install one package or another?

Tags: salt-stack

In order to successfully install something I need the add-apt-repository command, which happens to be inside `python-software-properties` on some distros or on `common-software-properties`.

That is the easiest way to write .sls file that will do this and install one of these packages.

Answer (score 2):

Use jinja conditionals and minion grains.

The following assumes I got the pairing correct for RedHat

```
add-apt-repository:
  pkgs.installed:
    - pkgs:
      {% if grains['os_family'] == 'RedHat' %}
      - common-software-properties
      {% elif grains['os_family'] == 'Debian' %}
      - python-software-properties
      {% endif %}
```

Comment: sorin, could you mark Dan's answer as "accepted" if it works for you? His answer is correct.